# The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety. For details, see

Tags: dart

I get the error in the title when trying to run the app. My dart version is 3.1.0.

Here is the content of the `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:

  sdk: ">=2.17.5 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.5.3+2
#  path: ^1.8.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  path_provider_macos: ^2.0.6
  sqflite: ^2.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  flutter_share: ^2.0.0

  social_share: ^2.2.1
#  share: ^0.6.5+3

  numberpicker: ^2.1.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  provider: ^6.0.3
  flutter_quill: ^5.2.11
#  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
#  rate_my_app: ^1.1.3
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  mime: ^1.0.2
  flutter_material_color_picker: ^1.1.0+2
  tuple: ^2.0.0
  package_info_plus: ^1.4.3
  flutter_mailer: ^2.0.1

  flutter_colorpicker: ^1.0.3
  html_unescape: ^2.0.0

  flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.8.5+3
  admob_flutter: ^3.0.0
  auto_direction: ^0.0.6
  html: ^0.15.0

  flutter_picker: ^2.0.5



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and make sure to **ask a question**. Do not just dump an error message or some configuration data, and expect others to know what the question is.

Comment: Is your package missing a `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information from https://dart.dev/guides/language/evolution

For example: To use null safety, introduced in 2.12, set 2.12.0 as the lower constraint in the pubspec.yaml file.

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
```